# Implementing svg with applied filter

Tags: html, svg, filter

I'm having trouble with implementing a svg-file on a website: Every file displays fine if it has no filters set in Inkscape. Exporting to .png works fine for every file but when I'm trying to display a file with a filter all parts of the svg-file with filter are not displayed.

Example of file without filter (sorry for the links, but it seems I aint got enough reputation points to post images...):

[image]

and with filter set:

[image]

As you can see, the "upper part" is not displayed because of a (shadow-)filter.

So, is it possible to display svg-files with filters or do I have to use css-effects for example for shadow effects?

Many thanks

EDIT:

Here is my HTML:

```
<img class="svg" src="img/favlabel3.svg">
```

Javascript I use for svg:

```
jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Replace image with new SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

    }, 'xml');
});
```

Comment: I don't think a shadow filter can make the upper part disappear. Could you post the code of the SVG?

Comment: We need to see the svg file i.e. favlabel3.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the Inkscape filters are using a feature not supported in web browsers, probably [`BackgroundImage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#AccessingBackgroundImage) (which allows a filter on one element to combine with elements behind it -- no browsers currently support it).

The specs do not offer any fallback options for filters, or any specific error handling guidelines.  Most browsers respond to errors in a filter by making the filtered graphic disappear, as you can see if you try [the example SVG from the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/filters/enable-background-01.svg).  (Compare with the [correctly rendered version as a PNG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/filters/enable-background-01.png).)

You'll need to figure out an alternative way to create the filter effect without using the background image.